# App Name Showing Twice - Routing Issue or Login Function Issue?

Tags: php, cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.3

I am having a small problem and I am not sure if its a routing issue or something is wrong with my login function. I have this ACL Plugin that I bought and integrated into my application. That said the login function is built into the plugin, so I edited my routing like so

```
 Router::connect('/', array('plugin' => 'AuthAcl', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'home'));


Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

Now the login will work but when I login it appears like this localhost/app/app
Instead of localhost/app.

I do not see anything wrong with the routing.

My login function is as follows

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'admin_login';
    $this->Session->delete('auth_user');
    App::uses('Setting', 'AuthAcl.Model');
    $Setting = new Setting();
    $error = null;

    $general = $Setting->find('first',array('conditions' => array('setting_key' => sha1('general'))));
    if (!empty($general)){
        $general = unserialize($general['Setting']['setting_value']);
    }

    $this->set('general',$general);

    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    if(!empty($user)){
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            if ((int)$this->request->data['User']['remember_me'] == 0){
                $this->Cookie->delete('AutoLoginUser');
            }else{
                $this->Cookie->write('AutoLoginUser', $this->Auth->user(), true, '+2 weeks');
            }
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $error = __('Your username or password was incorrect.');
        }
    }
    $this->set('error',$error);
```

Why am I not redirected correctly when I login.

Comment: Prior to 2.3 use ``return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());``
After 2.3 use ``return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());``. You tagged your question with 2.3, so change this and let us know if it is fixed

Comment: No it didn't. Strange.

Comment: If you place a ``return $this->redirect('/');`` before everything, where does it get you?

Comment: It said this page has a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is what I did to fix the problem. I pointed to the controller where I wanted the users to be redirected. Thanks user221931!

```
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl('auth_acl'));
```